# Class Random Java: The method "roll()" is undefined for type Random. Why?

Tags: java, random

I have to use method signature: public int roll()
I just don't understand why I can't call that method from my new random object. Please help.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Die {

    private int faceValue;
    private Random random;

    public Die() {
        Random r = new Random();
            r.roll(); // "The method roll() is undefined for the type Random
    }

    public int getFaceValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public int roll() {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            faceValue = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }
        return faceValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: your roll method is for your type Die, not for Random

Comment: Well, there simply is no mtehod `roll()` in [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), because it is a method of your class `Die`. Have you tried to just write `roll()` or `this.roll()`?

Comment: @deHaar without an instance of Die, that wouldn't compile

Comment: Your method `Die()` is your constructor, not your main. inside you should only instanciate a `Random` object, and affect it to your `random` attribute. Then, in the main method (that is currently absent of the code your showing) you should instanciate a `DIe` object, then call the `roll()` method on this object.

Comment: btw, did you mean to name your class `Dice` instead ?

Comment: @Stultuske the call to `roll()` is inside the constructor, I think it would compile... Sure, the random is not the one used in `roll()`...

Comment: @deHaar roll is an instance method, not a static one. no, it wouldn't compile without calling it on an actual instance of Die

Comment: @Stultuske in my eclipse, it does compile and really work... I just changed the code in the constructor to `this.random = new Random(); roll();` and created an instance of `Die` in the `main` of another class.

Comment: @Stutuske What? Ofc you can call instance methods from inside the class. See my answer, it compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You had few basic mistakes, here's a fixed version:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Die {
    private int faceValue;    
    private Random random;

    public Die() {
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public int getFaceValue()   {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public int roll()   {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
            faceValue = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }
        return faceValue;
    }
}
```

And then in your `main` method:

```
Die die = new Die();
System.out.println(die.roll());
```

Alternatively you can just `roll()` in the constructor:

```
public Die() {
    this.random = new Random();
    System.out.println(this.roll());
}
```

Comment: I have to call method roll() in my constructor for some reason. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @VitoNoble edited my answer to show the rolling in the constructor. Feel free to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel like it was helpful :)